# What is wrong with this wp_query?

Tags: posts, wp-query

I need to query posts by two meta fields and the wo_query I'm doing it with is returning nothing. Obviously, it's broken. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'espresso_event',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => 8,
                    'category_name' => 'homepage',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key' => 'event_start_date',
                            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'type' => 'DATE'
                            ),
                        array(
                            'key' => 'event_end_time',
                            'value' => date('g:i A'),
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'type' => 'TIME'
                            )
                        ),
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
                    'order' => 'ASC' // change this to ASC if you want newer events on top
                );
        // this saves the query to a temporary location so we can go back to it later after we run our query
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $wp_query->query($args);
```

The query works without this part:

```
array(
                            'key' => 'event_end_time',
                            'value' => date('g:i A'),
                            'compare' => '>=',
                            'type' => 'TIME'
                            )
```

So obviously the problem is there but I don't get an error or anything so I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: can we see an example of the dates passed in? Why are they different?

Comment: You are querying the `event_start_date` **and** the `event_end_time`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Tom J Nowell: Event id = 66, event_start_date = 2013-04-12 event_end_time = 22:00

Comment: vancoder: I want to pull the top 8 events that have not happened yet. They are not displayed if today's date is after event_start_date AND the current time is greater than event_end_time. So if today is April 12, 2013 at 8:00pm and the event is over on April 12, 2013 at 7:30pm the event won't be on the list.

Comment: Just a quick side-comment.  Why not just use "get_posts" instead of juggling all that stuff with the $wp_query variable?  As far as the main question, my guess would be a mismatch with the time value stored in the DB compared to date('g:i A').

Comment: Bryan, you need to prefix user names in comments with @ to get their attention.

Comment: does it make any difference to add `'relation' => 'AND'`?

Comment: @birgire `AND` should be the default setting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing and comparing your time in 24 hour format: 00:00:00.

```
array(
'key' => 'event_end_time',
 'value' => date('G:i:s'),
 'compare' => '>=',
 'type' => 'TIME'
)
```